# Photoshop Scripting: Replace an image

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a single photoshop file, and 200 image files (png).
Using the photoshop as a pattern, I need to generate 200 new images where each image is a result of a different png placed in the photoshop pattern.

Basically, replacing an image of a layer inside photoshop with external png file I have.

Is it something that can be done automatically using a photoshop script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the request I suggest using the Variables feature inside photoshop. Menu->Images->Variables

Then just select the layer you want to change and assign a variable name and choose "pixel replacement" behavior.

Outside Photoshop, create a text file with the variable name in the first line and the file names in new lines for each.

Go to menu-->file-->import-->variable datasets and browse for your text file.

If you see your error message then everything is correct.

Go to menu-->file-->export-->datasets to files and voila!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with scripting, you can do this. With a source image (psd) then load each of the 200 images and place it into the source file (then do what ever you want, save out the file) Switch back to the source file and carry on looping over the images till it's all done.

```
// must have source psd open to start with.

//pref pixels
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;


var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process");
if (inFolder != null)
{
  var fileList = inFolder.getFiles(/\.(png)$/i);
}


// main loop starts here
for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
  // load the frames one by one
  var doc = open(fileList[i]);

  var tempImage = app.activeDocument.name;

  //select all
  activeDocument.selection.selectAll()

  //copy image
  activeDocument.selection.copy();

  //close that document without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

  // select the source image
  activeDocument = srcDoc;

  getMeThisLayer("my favourite layer")

  //paste
  app.activeDocument.paste();

  //deselect all
  activeDocument.selection.deselect()

  var filePath = srcDoc.path + "/" + tempImage;

  // Flatten the image
  activeDocument.flatten();

  // save out the image
  var pngFile = new File(filePath);
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  pngSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
  pngSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE; pngSaveOptions.quality = 1;

  activeDocument.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);

  // close that save png
  app.activeDocument.close()
}



function getMeThisLayer(aLayerName)
{
  try
  {
    // try to find the layer
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName(aLayerName)
    return
  }

  catch(e)
  {
    //Whoops can't find layer
    alert("Can't find layer " + aLayerName + "\n" + e)
  }
}
```

Have fun.

Comment: This will just paste the image in a random place inside the psd..How can I instruct it to replace a specific layer or something similar..?

Comment: Waaah! You must remember that whilst you have the PSD files right in front of you, I don't.  You've only given a very short description of what you want doing. The better the description the easier it is for other people to help you out.  Note: This won't work if if there are groups(layer sets) in the file - again you didn't specify this. Regardless of that... I've added a function that will look for a layer, in this instance, one called "my favourite layer" change that to what ever it needs to be. Keep the quotes around it and exactly the same as it is in the psd file.